# How to write a query with different conditions on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

| ORG | SALE ID | CHARGE | MONTH |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 1 | 20 | NOV |
| AA | 2 | 30 | DEC |
| BB | 1 | 20 | DEC |
| BB | 2 | 00 | DEC |
| BB | 3 | 00 | DEC |
| BB | 1 | 20 | NOV |
| BB | 2 | 00 | NOV |
| CC | 3 | 00 | DEC |

I have the above table in a extended version. Basically I am looking to find the records for ORGs  that SUM of all the other CHARGES where SALE ID is NOT 1 is ZERO with respect to each MONTH.

so for the results I want to have something similar to below with respect to above table:

| ORG | MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| BB | NOV |
| BB | DEC |
| CC | DEC |

I tried various queries, but this is the latest one:

```
SELECT "MONTH", "ORG"
FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT "MONTH" , "CHARGE", "SALE_ID" ,"ORG" 
  CASE WHEN "SALE_ID" != 1  AND "SALE_ID" IS NOT NULL AND SUM("CHARGE") OVER(PARTITION BY "ORG", "MONTH" )=0
THEN "ORG" END 
  FROM "TABLE" WHERE 
"MONTH" >= '01-JAN-2023'  )
GROUP BY    "MONTH", "ORG"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, but there are a few issues.

1. Subquery missing an alias
2. Case statement is not being used to generate a new column.
3. Depending on your month column, '01-JAN-2023' this will not work.

I've rewritten your query, it should probably look something like this. You might need to revise the filtering.

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT "ORG"
        ,"MONTH"
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN "SALE_ID" != 1 THEN "CHARGE"
                ELSE 0 END) AS OtherCharges
        ,MAX(CASE WHEN "SALE_ID" = 1 THEN "CHARGE"
                ELSE 0 END) AS Sale1Charge
    FROM "TABLE"
    WHERE "MONTH" IN ('NOV','DEC', '...')
    GROUP BY "ORG","MONTH"
    )
SELECT "ORG","MONTH"
FROM cte
WHERE OtherCharges = 0 AND Sale1Charge > 0
```

Comment: This seems overly complicated as: you do not need to use double quotes around upper-case identifiers; and you do not need to use a sub-query factoring clause (CTE) and can move the filters and aggregation into a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @MT0  using "HAVING" clause didn't solve my problem, that was my first choice writing the query and it wasn't coming back with accurate results. "CTE" was the solution to my problem.

Comment: @Mr.Jones  This is great it solved the problem for me with accurate result.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HAVING` clause and conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT org,
       month
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY
       org, month
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN sale_id != 1 THEN charge END) = 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ORG, SALE_ID, CHARGE, MONTH) AS
SELECT 'AA', 1, 20, 'NOV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'AA', 2, 30, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB', 1, 20, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB', 2, 00, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB', 3, 00, 'DEC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB', 1, 20, 'NOV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'BB', 2, 00, 'NOV' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'CC', 3, 00, 'DEC' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ORG | MONTH |
| --- | --- |
| CC | DEC |
| BB | NOV |
| BB | DEC |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iZLUGfez)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT "MONTH" , "ORG" 
FROM "TABLE" 
WHERE "SALE_ID" != 1
GROUP BY "MONTH" , "ORG"
HAVING sum("CHARGE") = 0
```